# "subtracting" strings, classes in python

Tags: python, class

Learning about classes in python. I want the difference between two strings, a sort of subtraction. eg:

```
a = "abcdef"
b ="abcde"
c = a - b
```

This would give the output f.

I was looking at this class and I am new to this so would like some clarification on how it works.

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __init__(self, val):
        return str.__init__(self, val)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.count(other) > 0:
            return self.replace(other, '', 1)
        else:
            return self
```

and this will work in the following way:

```
>>> a = MyStr('thethethethethe')
>>> b = a - 'the'
>>> a
'thethethethethe'
>>> b
'thethethethe'
>>> b = a - 2 * 'the'
>>> b
'thethethe'
```

So a string is passed to the class and the constructor is called `__init__`. This runs the constructor and an object is returned, which contains the value of the string? Then a new subtraction function is created, so that when you use `-` with the MyStr object it is just defining how subtract works with that class? When sub is called with a string, count is used to check if that string is a substring of the object created. If that is the case, the first occurrence of the passed string is removed. Is this understanding correct?

Edit: basically this class could be reduced to:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __sub__(self, other):
            return self.replace(other, '', 1)
```

Comment: Note: You don't need to define ``__init__`` if you are not doing anything else than calling the super class.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but note, however, that `a - "the"*2` will not give the same result as `(a - "the") - "the"`.  In fact, the second will produce an error.

Comment: @RoadieRich why would this give an error?

Comment: @Paul `a - "the"` returns the result of `self.replace(...)`, which is a `str`. Then you're trying to subtract the second `"the"` from a `str`, which is an invalid operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is entirely correct.

Python will call a `.__sub__()` method if present on the left-hand operand; if not, a corresponding `.__rsub__()` method on the right-hand operand can also hook into the operation.

See [emulating numeric types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for a list of hooks Python supports for providing more arithmetic operators.

Note that the `.count()` call is redundant; `.replace()` will not fail if the `other` string is not present; the whole function could be simplified to:

```
def __sub__(self, other):
    return self.replace(other, '', 1)
```

The reverse version would be:

```
def __rsub__(self, other):
    return other.replace(self, '', 1)
```

Comment: A note to the OP: the entire `__sub__` function should probably just be: `return self.replace(other, '', 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is rsub like sub but works from the right or? if I try rsub then '-' does not work because I'm assuming it's not hooked in to work with that off the bat? Cool, the class is now edited  in my OP to three lines.

Comment: Added a reverse version for you; for the reverse the original expression would be `other - self`, so you'd have to adjust the code accordingly. Try `'thethethethe' - MyStr('the')` to see that in action.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah perfect, see what you mean now. Thanks!